# Calculate grouped rolling cumulative sum with multiplier

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the rolling cumulative sum after multiplying a column by a constant within a Pandas DataFrame. For example, given the series:

```
0
0
1
0
0
0
```

I would like to apply a constant multiple, for example 1.5, to cumulatively to compute the following series:

```
0
0
1
1.5
2.25
3.375
```

The series will need to be calculated over a group, for example:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'Value': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
```

Should compute for `a` and `b` respectively.

The series will only ever contain either `0` or `1` as values, and `1` will only occur once in the series. As such the sum of a series **before** any computation is `1`.

Comment: What should happen if series is `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`?

Comment: Good question ASGM, I should make this clear within the question. This is impossible in the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one-liner but it produces the output in the same `Value` column, since it only has `0` or `1` multiplying `1 time x` is the same as `0 + x`

```
df.iloc[df.Value.idxmax()+1:, df.columns == 'Value'] =
    (df.iloc[df.Value.idxmax()+1:, df.columns == 'Value']+1.5).cumprod()

df.Value
#   Value
# 0 0.0
# 1 0.0
# 2 1.0
# 3 1.5
# 4 2.25
# 5 3.375
```

**EDIT**

If this require to be applied only for a specific group better to create a function

```
def fun(df_g):
    df = df_g.copy()
    df.iloc[df.Value.idxmax()+1:, df.columns == 'Value'] = 
        (df.iloc[df.Value.idxmax()+1:, df.columns == 'Value']+1.5).cumprod()
    return df.Value

df_result = df.groupby('Group').apply(fun).\
    transform(pd.Series).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

df_result
# Group 0
# a 0.0
# a 0.0
# a 1.0
# a 1.5
# b 0.0
# b 0.0
```

Comment: Can you convert to be a function that OP can apply by group?  I can if not, but don't want to interfere unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks @ASGM better to provide both solutions.